# jQuery dropdown menu with setTimeout does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, settimeout

I know this questions being asked many times already but I can not make my drop down menu work with what I have so far. The problem appears if I set delay for menu to show, without setTimeout the menu works just fine. Could anyone take a look and suggest the solution please? I am also trying that it works in IE6.

- Here is the full example with setTimeout:
  http://jsbin.com/owoyon/1/ (bugged, does not work correct, drop downs get stuck, delay is not recognized)
- here is a working version without setTimeout
  http://jsbin.com/isamay/1/

and here is a code copy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    body {margin:60px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
    ul,ul ul {margin:0;padding:0;} 
    ul li {
        position:relative;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:5px 0;
        margin:0 10px;
        cursor:pointer;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;     
    }
    .submenu {
        background:#eee;
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        width:200px;        
        top:25px;
        left:0;
        margin-left:-5px;
    }
    .hover {
        display:block !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li class="drop">Option 1
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            </ul>          
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="drop">Option 2
    <div class="submenu">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            </ul>          
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    (function(){

        var topNav = $('#navigation'),
            drop = topNav.find('.drop'),
            myTimer;                

        drop.hover(function(){                  
            obj = $(this);                      
            subMenu = obj.find('.submenu');         
            subMenu.addClass('hover');  
            clearTimeout(myTimer);              
        },function(){
            myTimer = setTimeout(function(){                
                subMenu.removeClass('hover');   
            },300);                                             
        });     

    })();   

});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work it out. Demo here http://jsbin.com/owoyon/3/edit

```
var topNav = $('#navigation'),
    drop = topNav.find('.drop'),
    myTimer;

drop.hover(function () {
    var obj = $(this);
    var subMenu = obj.find('.submenu');
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    if (subMenu.hasClass('hover')) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        drop.find('.submenu').removeClass('hover');
        subMenu.addClass('hover');
    }
}, function () {
    myTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        drop.find('.submenu').removeClass('hover');
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: That is almost correct, the problem is that if you quick mousesout from submenu and then get back to it while it is still open it will close it anyway after delay expires. That should not be happening, do you think its fixable?

Comment: Alex, I've fixed that. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your JS code and try this

```
var topNav = $('#navigation'),
            drop = topNav.find('.drop'),
            myTimer, subMenu;                

$('#navigation .drop').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    obj.hover(function(){

        subMenu = obj.find('.submenu');
        subMenu.addClass('hover');
    },function(){
            myTimer = setTimeout(function(){                
                obj.find('.submenu').removeClass('hover');    
            },300);                                                   
     });
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bvhk2/1/