# jQuery dropdown mouseout delay

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a navigation system that involves a dropdown menu allowing the user to reach the 2nd and 3rd level rollouts. On hover the parent menu stays active as well as changes in arrow direction occur.

The trouble I'm having is allowing the user to run off the dropdown menu and it stays for roughly 1 second, however if the user returns back to the parent I want the dropdown to disappear (to avoid ghosting).

Although I appear to have the jQuery working, I would like to know how to clean it up specifically the hover function as I have a lot of repetitive code. Or is there a much easier way to achieve this?

I've searched around this community and found [jQuery dropdown menu with setTimeout does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138951/jquery-dropdown-menu-with-settimeout-does-not-work) which did help to write what I have. Any questions please ask and any help on this would be massively appreciated!! Cheers.

For a visual representation of what I mean, I've created a jsfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/hoffismo/4b9jL7t4/5/.

HTML code below:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first expanded"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="last expanded"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expanded"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
                <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery code below:

```
// Add arrows for the navigation.
$('nav ul > li').each(function () {
    var _this = $(this);

    // Set timer for fade out.
    var timer = null;

    // Arrows stored as data ready to be fetched.
    $('a').data('arrows', {
        up: ' <i>&#65514;</i>',
        right: ' <i>&#65515;</i>',
        down: ' <i>&#65516;</i>',
        left: ' <i>&#65513;</i>'
    });

    // Initially add the down and right arrows.
    if (_this.not('li ul li').find('ul').length > 0) {
        _this.children('a').append($('a').data('arrows').down);
    } else if (_this.find('ul').length > 0) {
        _this.children('a').append($('a').data('arrows').right);
    }

    // Hover events for both mouseover and mouseout.
    _this.hover(function () {
        // Reset the timer if user hovers back over.
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
        // Second level mouseover.
        if (!_this.children('a').hasClass('active') && _this.not('li ul li').find('ul').length > 0) {
            $('li ul > li').mouseover(function (e) {
                // Reset the timer if user hovers back over.
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = null;
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (_this.children('a').hasClass('active')) {
                    _this.children('a').addClass('active');
                    _this.children('ul').addClass('fadeout');
                }
            });
            _this.has('ul').children('a').addClass('active');
            _this.children('a').find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').up);
        }
        // Third level mouseover.
        else if (!_this.children('a').hasClass('active') && _this.find('ul').length > 0) {
            $('li ul li ul > li').mouseover(function (e) {
                // Reset the timer if user hovers back over.
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = null;
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (_this.children('a').hasClass('active')) {
                    _this.children('a').addClass('active');
                    _this.children('ul').addClass('fadeout');
                }
            });
            _this.has('ul').children('a').addClass('active');
            _this.children('a').find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').left);
        }
    },

    function () {
        // Second level mouseout.
        if (_this.children('a').hasClass('active') && _this.not('li ul li').find('ul').length > 0) {
            $('li ul > li').mouseout(function (e) {
                // Reset the timer if user hovers back over.
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = null;
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (_this.children('ul').hasClass('fadeout')) {
                    _this.children('a').addClass('active');
                    timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        _this.children('a').removeClass('active');
                        _this.children('ul').removeClass('fadeout');
                        _this.children('a').find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').down);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
            _this.children('a').removeClass('active');
            _this.children('ul').removeClass('fadeout');
            _this.children('a').find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').down);
        }
        // Third level mouseout.
        else if (_this.children('a').hasClass('active') && _this.find('ul').length > 0) {
            $('li ul li ul > li').mouseout(function (e) {
                // Reset the timer if user hovers back over.
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = null;
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (_this.children('ul').hasClass('fadeout')) {
                    _this.children('a').addClass('active');
                    timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        _this.children('a').removeClass('active');
                        _this.children('ul').removeClass('fadeout');
                        _this.children('a').find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').right);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
            _this.children('a').removeClass('active');
            _this.children('ul').removeClass('fadeout');
            _this.children('a').find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').right);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this after finding a very helpful post on CSS Tricks at https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/.

I used the 'Widening CSS Boundaries' approach after taking a look at the following [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Alhadis/pen/FsEjz) which is linked within the article. This involves adding another div and extending the area of this outside of the submenu which effectively keeps the dropdown menu active. All with the power of CSS!

I also trimmed the entire hover function back to the below:

```
  // Add arrows for desktop version of the navigation.
  $('nav ul > li').each(function() {
    // Defining variables.
    var _this = $(this);
    var listitems = _this.children('a');

    // Arrows stored as data ready to be fetched.
    $('a').data('arrows', {
      up: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>',
      right: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
      down: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>',
      left: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>'
    });

    // Initially add the down and right arrows.
    if (_this.not('li ul li').find('ul').length > 0) {
      listitems.prepend($('a').data('arrows').down);
    }
    else if (_this.find('ul').length > 0) {
      listitems.prepend($('a').data('arrows').right);
    }

    // Hover events for both mouseover and mouseout.
    _this.hover(function() {
      // Second level mouseover.
      if (!listitems.hasClass('active') && _this.not('li ul li').find('ul').length > 0) {
        listitems.addClass('active');
        listitems.find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').up);
      }
      // Third level mouseover.
      else if (!listitems.hasClass('active') && _this.find('ul').length > 0) {
        listitems.addClass('active');
        listitems.find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').left);
      }
    },
    function() {
      // Second level mouseout.
      if (listitems.hasClass('active') && _this.not('li ul li').find('ul').length > 0) {
        listitems.removeClass('active');
        listitems.find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').down);
      }
      // Third level mouseout.
      else if (listitems.hasClass('active') && _this.find('ul').length > 0) {
        listitems.removeClass('active');
        listitems.find('i').replaceWith($('a').data('arrows').right);
      }
    });
  });
```